# How to check if a file is present in a particular directory in Unix?

Tags: unix

I am new to Unix and I want to know how to check if a file is present in a particular directory in Unix?
Please help me through this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of [ls] and [$?] command to do this.
Use below command :

> ls -l filename.txt

Followed by,

> echo $?

If the file exists, the [ls] command will be successful.Hence [echo $?] will print 0.
If the file does not exists, then [ls] command will fail and hence [echo $?] will print 1.